# How to not inherit width in css?

Tags: css

So I have this html:

```
<p>here is some <span>random</span> content that I might use</p>​
```

and this css:

```
span{
    position: relative;
}

span:before{
    content: 'this is more content';
    position:absolute;
    color: red;
    top: -15px;
}
```

What happens is, the content added with css inherits the width of the `span` (the word 'random'). is there a way to remove the inherited width **without** adding a width value to override  the inheritance

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/7dBbZ/1/
Thanks
    ​

Comment: `width` is not implicitly inherited in any way. What makes you think it is?

Comment: @BoltClock based on the demo (added above) - maybe the word inherit might be wrong, but it seems like it is inheriting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `white-space:nowrap;` since the element is rendered with `display:inline`. It doesn't actually inherit `width`, as BoltClock has pointed out it is *not* an implicitly inherited property, but rather fills the parent element with wrapping allowed.

http://jsfiddle.net/7dBbZ/5/

Try playing with different values for `content` and see for yourself (i.e. with text shorter than the parent element, text without spaces etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
span:before {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```